# Android custom view without setting layout_height property in xml

Tags: android

I want to create a custom view and have fields `layout_height` and `layout_width` non-mandatory in xml (it would have default values). Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: you can, just add them at runtime to your main layout.

Comment: What is the view for? You can give them values like `wrap_content` or `0dp` in the xml and then vary the size in Java.